# map multiple properties to single nested object using typescript and class-transformer

Tags: typescript, nestjs, class-transformer

I'm using class-transformer (in nestjs) to convert my database entities into dto types to output from my api.

My database entities look like:

```js
class MyEntity {
  id: string;
  property1: string;
  property2: string;
}
```

but my API needs to output something like

```js
class NestedDto {
  property1: string;
  property2: string;
}

class MyDto {
  id: string;
  nested: NestedDto;
}
```

So, using class-transformer, how do I combine those two properties into a single nested object?

I've tried using `@Transform` like this:

```js
class MyDto {
  @Expose()
  id: string;

  @Transform(p => ( property1: p.obj.property1, property2: p.obj.property2 }));
  nested: any;
}
```

it technically works, but it doesn't scale and isn't very clean.

Is there a nicer way to achieve this using class-transformer?

Also, for bonus points, if those two properties are null in the database, it would be nice for the nested property on the api to not exist - though this is nice-to-have, and not a requirement :)

Answer (score 0):

```
class MyDto {
  @Expose()
  id: string;

  @Transform((p: MyEntity) => ( property1: p.obj.property1, property2: p.obj.property2 }));
  @IsOptional()
  nested: NestedDto;
}
```

YOLO I never used nestjs

Answer (score 0):

```
  @Transform(({ value, obj }) => {
value = new Card();
value.expiration = obj.expiryDate;
return value;}) productForeignCard: Card;
```

try this

Comment: Welcome to Stack Overflow. Code is a lot more helpful when it is accompanied by an explanation. Stack Overflow is about learning, not providing snippets to blindly copy and paste. Please [edit] your answer and explain how it answers the specific question being asked. See [answer].

Answer (score 0):

I had the same problem, I wanted to map a [geoJson](https://geojson.org/) data to a more humain friendly one `{'long':..., 'lat':...}`, which means map the input data and the output data.
I apply this as an input DTO to convert the schema above into geojson.

```
@ValidateNested({ each: true }),
@Type(() => DBLocationDto),
@Transform(
  ({ value }) =>
    morphism(
      {
        type: () => 'Point',
        coordinates: iteratee => [iteratee.lng, iteratee.lat],
      },
      value,
      HumainLocationDto,
    ),
  { toPlainOnly: true }
)
```

Then in my output DTO I have almost the same, in the opposite

```
@Type(() => HumainLocationDto),
@Transform(
  ({ value }) =>
    morphism(
      {
        lng: iteratee => iteratee.coordinates[0],
        lat: iteratee => iteratee.coordinates[1],
      },
      value,
      DBLocationDto,
    ),
  { toClassOnly: true },
)
```

As you can see I am using morphism to map my to classes, but you can do it directly by yourself.

PS: I had an issue when the location is not present at all, it was considered as if it was optional, I fixed it by forcing the definition with `@IsDefined()`

Answer (score 0):

Also, you can make like this:

```
class NestedDto {
  @Expose()
  property1: string;
  @Expose()
  property2: string;
}

class MyDto {
  id: string;

  @Transform((data) => plainToClass(NestedDto, data.obj, { strategy: 'excludeAll' }))
  nested: NestedDto;
}
```